# Class attributes initialization with array - java

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I would know a better way to initialize this kind of class:

```
public class TestClass{
    private byte[] attribute0;
    private customClass0 attribute1;
    private customClass1 attribute2;
    ...

    public TestClass(byte[] args){
        int offset = 0;
        byte[] argsCustomClass0;
        byte[] argsCustomClass1;
        System.arraycopy(args, offset, attribute0, 0, attribute0.length);
        offset += attribute0.length;
        System.arraycopy(args, offset, argsCustomClass0, 0, argsCustomClass0.length);
        offset += attribute0.length;
        attribute1 = new CustomClass1(argsCustomClass0);
        System.arraycopy(args, offset, argsCustomClass1, 0, argsCustomClass1.length);
        offset += argsCustomClass1.length;
        attribute2 = new customClass1(argsCustomClass1);
        ...
    }
```

This is working but it's pretty "dirty coding", does anyone knows another way to initialize these attributes using an array? I precise that my args array could be very large an my attributes number as well.

Thanks!

Flo

Answer (score 2):

Use an array of arrays:

```
public class TestClass{
    private byte[][] attributes;
    // -----^^^^^^^^

    public TestClass(byte[] args){
        int offset = 0;
        for (byte[] a : attributes) {
            System.arraycopy(args, offset, a, 0, a.length);
            offset += a.length;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the problem is that each attribute has a different size, and sometimes, it could be a different type (byte[], int[], String etc...) but all these ones shall be initialized by bytes contained in the args array

Comment: @F.Delamare: Different sizes aren't a problem (Java has arrays of arrays, not 2D arrays; arrays of arrays are inherently jagged.) If they have different types, you should have shown that in the question and shown exactly how you're using the different types if you want an answer that correctly addresses that.

Comment: You are right, my question was not precise enough, I've just modified it.

Comment: @F.Delamare: The update doesn't use `attribute1` or `attribute2` anywhere. It *sets* them, but it doesn't *use* them. Again, we can't help you if we don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: I just want to set all the attribute in a better way that the one I use.

Comment: @F.Delamare: Yes, we know. But again, we can't help you do that if we don't know how you're *using* `attribute1`, etc., in your code.